# Rails active storage issue with deleting individual uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I am saving some files to local storage via active storage. I am displaying them as links on my page. They could be pdfs, images, word docs etc. I want to have a link next to it to be able to delete the individual files but haven't gotten it to work yet. Here is what I have:

Projects Model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :user

has_one :proj_status, :foreign_key => "status_id", :primary_key => 'status_id'

has_many_attached :uploads

end
```

Projects Show Page:

```
<%= link_to upload.filename, rails_blob_path(upload, disposition: :attachment) %>

<%= link_to 'Remove', delete_upload_project_url(upload.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Projects Controller delete upload method:

```
def delete_upload

attachment = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])

attachment.purge # or use purge_later

redirect_back(fallback_location: projects_path)

end
```

I get the error:

No route matches [GET] "/projects/1/delete_upload"

I am thinking this is a routing issue but I haven't been able to get it to work yet.

Also here is my routes section:

```
resources :projects do

  member do

  delete :delete_upload

  end

end
```

Any thoughts or ideas on how to get this working?

Here is my rake routes for the projects section:

```
DELETE /projects/:id/delete_upload/:upload_id(.:format) projects#delete_upload

projects GET /projects(.:format) projects#index

POST /projects(.:format) projects#create

new_project GET /projects/new(.:format) projects#new

edit_project GET /projects/:id/edit(.:format) projects#edit

project GET /projects/:id(.:format) projects#show

PATCH /projects/:id(.:format) projects#update

PUT /projects/:id(.:format) projects#update

DELETE /projects/:id(.:format) projects#destroy
```

If anyone can help me with this I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was set up correctly from the get go. The problem was that I had accidentally removed the include for application.js from my project. The lack of UJS reference was causing all requests to be gets instead of the delete in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Your `delete_upload_project_url` method expect two variables: a project and an upload `/projects/:id/delete_upload/:upload_id`. You are only passing the upload id. Do something like `delete_upload_project_url(project.id, upload.id)`.

Comment: Thanks so when I cahnge the link_to to <%= link_to 'Remove', delete_upload_project_url(@project.id, upload.id), method: :delete_upload, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

I get a No route matches [GET] "/projects/6/delete_upload.1"

Comment: `method` is the HTTP method to use on the request, not the actual method name of your action, do `method: :delete` instead of `method: :delete_upload`. I don't know why you changed that, it's ok on your original question.

Comment: Changing the link_to back to method: delete produces the same error:

No route matches [GET] "/projects/1/delete_upload.6"

Comment: Try with `delete_upload_project_url(id: project.id, upload_id: upload.id)`. Anyway, I think it would be easier for you to use Rails' convention to handle CRUD operation on nested resources, check the guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: Thanks so when I change the link_to to what you specified above I get a No route matches [GET] "/projects/1/delete_upload". So for some reason it doesn't have the ID of the upload maybe? Looking at the nested resouces, this would mean I would need to create an uploads controller and model correct?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that you are not using nested resources, you have attachments so using nested resources routing seems too much for that. Try with `url_for(controller: :projects, action: :delete_upload, id: project.id, upload_id: upload.id)`, your rake routes ouput shows that, I don't understand why it keeps saying there's no route for that.

Comment: Yeah I don't get it. Changing to URL_for I get the same No route matches [GET] "/projects/1/delete_upload" error:

When I mouse over the remove link this is the link. http://localhost:3000/projects/1/delete_upload?upload_id=1 The ids match up correctly so I'm not sure why I am getting the route error.